# how to use ng-if in showing if an item is defined in the list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have tried to use ng-if in selecting an item in the list to know if this is defined or not using ng-if 
here is my angular code

```
function ($scope) {
    var dirlist = this;
    dirlist.list = [{
            name: 'laugh',
            time: 10
        },
        {
            name: 'eat',
            time: 12
        }, {
            name: 'work out',
            time: 11
        }, {
            name: 'make something',
            time: 13
        }];
}
```

and i want to ask if the list contains a name called heo
to add a vioce to it using
html

```
<div ng-if="dirlist.list.indexof(hio)!== -1 "  class="list-item">
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="audio\Hio Hio Hio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: indexof should be indexOf

Comment: indexOf can only be used in this way, when your elements are numbers or strings but not objects.

Comment: index of can be used for objects @Blauharley

Comment: i wrote it before it is not the problem the problem is i do not know how to call a certain place where the name is mentioned when using this in angular and each list contain many items

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, but not in this way (in the question), you have to put a reference of a "element-object" into indexof, as its done [here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/finding-array-elements-with-array-indexof.html). So there shoudl be a ng-repeat to interate over these objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function that checks the name property of each object in the array. It returns true if it finds "hio".

```
function checkHio(){
    for (var i=0; i < dirlist.list.length; i++) {
        if (dirlist.list[i].name === 'hio') {
            return true;
        }
    }
  return false;
}
```

Then you can call this function in ng-if directive.

```
<div ng-if="checkHio()"  class="list-item">
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="audio\Hio Hio Hio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it worked with adding a dirlist,checkhio= function() instead

Comment: and in the ng-if dirlist.checkHio()

Comment: @MohamedAbdelhady I'm glad it worked. You can also optimize the function by using a Array.filter method.